# How to set custom default value of angular material component

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

It's possible to define custom value to @angular/material properties?

I'm using mat-paginator in my application and i'm trying to change the `.mat-paginator-range-label {margin: 0 32px 0 24px}` to `.mat-paginator-range-label{margin:auto}` but i coudn't change it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use ng-deep, it's deprecated

override material style in your styles.scss

```
body .mat-paginator-range-label {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you want to override the css properties for class `.mat-paginator-range-label` and `.mat-paginator-range-label` for that you can use ::ng-deep

```
::ng-deep .mat-paginator-range-label {margin: 0 32px 0 24px}

::ng-deep .mat-paginator-range-label{margin:auto}
```

or

```
::ng-deep{
.mat-paginator-range-label {margin: 0 32px 0 24px}
.mat-paginator-range-label{margin:auto}
}
```